# Revised: SQL constraint to enforce column2 value based on column1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, constraints

I need to create a table check constraint to achieve the following:

1. If column1 is null, then column2 **must** be null
2. If column1 is not null, then column2 can be either null or not null

I've written this constraint, but just wondered if you pro's could cast your expert eyes on it.  I have achieve this correctly, or in the best way?

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT [const_name] CHECK
(
(Column1 IS NULL AND Column2 IS NULL) OR 
(Column1 IS NOT NULL AND (Column2 IS NOT NULL OR Column2 IS NULL))
)
```

Comment: The problem is that column1 can have a value without column2 having a value, but no the other way around.

Comment: I've changed my approach which should hopefully clarify things.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler form, based on your new rules:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT [const_name] CHECK
(
    (Column2 IS NULL OR Column1 IS NOT NULL)
)
```

Think about it - if `Column2` is `null` then we don't need to assert anything about `Column1` - it can be `NULL` or not and you're happy.

Similarly, if `Column1` is *not* `NULL` then we don't care whether `Column2` is `NULL` or not.

The only case where we want this constraint to fail is specifically when `Column2` isn't `NULL` but `Column1` is - exactly the false case for the above `OR` condition.

Comment: Damn you're fast.  I was currently revising the question to use Bitfields instead of NULL/NOT NULL.  Would it be the same approach?  I can revise the question still if you'd prefer?

Comment: @EvilDr - yes, you can apply similar logic for 1s and 0s as you would for `NOT NULL` and `NULL`.

Comment: Like this?  `(Column2=0 OR Column1<>1)` to represent that if column1 is false then column2 MUST be false, but if column1 is true then column2 can be either true/false

Comment: @EvilDr- `(Column2=0 OR Column1=1)`. Yours would be satisfied by `Column1` being 0 for any `Column2` value, which isn't what's wanted.

Comment: Just given it a try on a temp table.  Stunning - thank you very much